# How do I gradually change the color of navbar on scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, html, navbar, nav

I have a transparent navbar which I would like to gradually change color until it is finally opaque as it passes below a div. I have this:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var dHeight = $(this).height()-$(window).height();
  if (dHeight >= $(this).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').css('background', 'rgba(53,145,204,' + $(this).scrollTop() / dHeight + ')');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  background: rgba(53, 145, 204, 0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Scroll me...
  </div>
</div>
```

... so far but rather than taking the entire height of the page to become opaque I would like it to have become opaque after it reaches the bottom of a div, could anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. Certainly it can be done.. check this out.. it will make your  opaque as soon as you have finished scrolling through your div with the text Scroll me ...

And kindly correct me if I have misinterpreted your question.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var dHeight = $("#nav1").height();
  var alpha = (($(this).scrollTop() / dHeight ) / 10);
  $('#changeBg').css('background', 'rgba(53,145,204,' +(alpha * 2)  + ')');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#changeBg{
  background: rgba(53, 145, 204, 0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="changeBg">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div id="nav1">
    Scroll me...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please mark it correct and vote it up@hyphynutcookie

Answer (score 1):

Here I have fetched height of div. So, your `nav` will now become opaque at scroll you require.

Here I have attached fiddle. Hope this will help you.

[jsfiddele](https://jsfiddle.net/fLruvfxs/)

Answer (score 0):

[Is this the one you expecting?](https://jsfiddle.net/tmf773ab/)

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

Scroll me...

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  background: rgba(53, 145, 204, 0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var dHeight = $(this).height()-$(window).height();
  if (dHeight >= $(this).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').css('background', 'rgba(53,145,204,' + $(this).scrollTop() + ')');
  }
});
```